# Adding debian/ubuntu repo key without apt-key (from keyserver.ubuntu.com)

Tags: ansible, debian, apt

As you probably know, since debian 11 command apt-key is deprecated and it will be removed.
The "right" way to add a repository key is to copy it to /usr/share/keyrings (and specify signed-by= into repository file). Most programs provide a link from the gpg key (binary or ascii armored), but when you have only the key id it's a little tricky when you don't know what to do it (and google it's not your friend)
See my answer for this simple solution (for ubuntu keyserver, I didn't ever use other), hope it will save someone's time!

Comment: You are confusing `apt-key` the binary and `apt_key`, the Ansible module. In later versions of Ansible, the later does not use the former anymore, so your "issue" is not one.

Comment: i've just read the latest documentation, quote:
"The apt-key command has been deprecated and suggests to ‘manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead’. See the Debian wiki for details. This module is kept for backwards compatibility for systems that still use apt-key as the main way to manage apt repository keys."
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html

Comment: also the recommended way for 3rd party repositories is to keep the repo keys in /usr/share/keyrings and like i've said add an signed-by=/path/to/repo.key as repo option
i do not know of any other "trends" (other than maybe use the new "full" format of the repository - but now it's only supported, not recommended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download the key from the keyserver.ubuntu.com key repo, use this example for ansible repository:

```
wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/ansible.asc "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x6125E2A8C77F2818FB7BD15B93C4A3FD7BB9C367"
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ansible.asc] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ansible.list
```

you will need the signing key id (6125E2A8C77F2818FB7BD15B93C4A3FD7BB9C367 is the key for ansible repo hosted on launchpad), and of course repo url and key filename will differ for you, depending on the repository you're trying to add

of course, if you are using some configuration management (i.e. ansible, puppet, chef) there is a module to be called (for ansible: get_url), so that url and maybe file locations are the "answer" you're looking for

ubuntu keyserver provides repo key in ascii armored format, so you must use the .asc file extension

you will not need to de-armor the file (especially when you are using an ansible role/playbook), also you will not need to install gpg packages (other than those on a "base" debian installation)

hope it helps!

Comment: also it works with the "short" key id (in my example: https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x93C4A3FD7BB9C367&fingerprint=on&op=get)